# How to get enum value in angular js with a response data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I have a problem, I confused to get enum value in angular js. Oke, I have table list, the column 'Criteria Type' there are two values from mysql : 'C' is Cost and 'B' is Benefit. But my table list just display "C" or "B". So, how can i get/make enum value by initial string 'C' to be Cost and 'B' to be benefit?
Here my code controller :

```
 adminService.get('kriteria').then(function(response){
    $scope.datas = response.data;
});
```

and here my display data table code :

```
<div class = "panel-body">
            <div id="add-button"><a href="#!/kriteria/0" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin:5px 5px 5px 10px">Tambah Kriteria</a></div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead><tr><th>No</th><th>Code Kriteria</th><th>Nama Kriteria</th><th>Criteria Type</th><th>Skala Kepentingan</th><th>Proses</th></tr></thead>
                <tbody><tr ng-repeat="(v,i) in datas"><td>{{v+1}}</td><td>{{i.kd_kriteria}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.nama_kriteria}}</td><td>{{i.jenis_kriteria}}</td><td>{{i.id_skala}}</td><td><a href="#!/kriteria/{{i.id_kriteria}}">Edit</a> |
                        <a href="" ng-click="delete(i.id_kriteria)">Hapus</a></td></tr></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Code Service :

```
/** adminControl Service **/
app.service('adminService', ['$http', '$route', function($http, $route){
    var links = "./services/";

    this.get = function(url){
        return $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:links + url,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }

    this.post = function(url,data){
        return $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:links + url,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data
        });
    }

    this.update = function(url,data){
        return $http({
            method:'UPDATE',
            url:links + url,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data
        });
    }

    this.delete = function(url) {
        return $http({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: links + url,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }

    this.getReload = function(url){
        $route.reload();
        location.href=url;
    }
}]);
```

And my API in php code :

```
function kriteria(){
        switch($this->get_request_method()){
            case "GET":
                if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
                    $result = NULL;
                    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_kriteria, tbl_skala
                                                WHERE tbl_kriteria.id_skala = tbl_skala.id_skala ORDER BY 1 DESC");
                    $sql->execute();
                    while($r = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        $result[] = $r;
                    }
                    return $this->response($this->json($result));
                }else{
                    $result = NULL;
                    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_kriteria
                                                WHERE id_kriteria = '".$_GET['id']."'
                                                ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 1");
                    $sql->execute();
                    if($sql->rowCount()){
                        $r = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $result = $r;
                        return $this->response($this->json($result));
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "POST":
                $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
                $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_kriteria (id_skala, kd_kriteria, nama_kriteria, jenis_kriteria)
                                            VALUES (:id_skala, :kd_kriteria, :nama_kriteria, :jenis_kriteria)");
                $sql->bindParam(':id_skala', $data['id_skala']);
                $sql->bindParam(':kd_kriteria', $data['kd_kriteria']);
                $sql->bindParam(':nama_kriteria', $data['nama_kriteria']);
                $sql->bindParam(':jenis_kriteria', $data['jenis_kriteria']);
                $sql->execute();
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_kriteria WHERE id_kriteria = '".$_GET['id']."'");
                $sql->execute();
                break;
            case 'UPDATE':
                $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
                $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_kriteria set kd_kriteria = '".$data['kd_kriteria']."',
                                            nama_kriteria = '".$data['nama_kriteria']."', jenis_kriteria = '".$data['jenis_kriteria']."'
                                            id_skala = '".$data['id_skala']."' WHERE id_kriteria = '".$data['id_kriteria']."'");
                $sql->execute();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Give the complete code of service. And backend

Comment: Oke master, Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you want to create a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

```
app.filter('criteriaFilter', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var myEnum = {
        "C": "Cost",
        "B": "Benefit",
    };
    return myEnum[input];
  }
});
```

And in your view:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in criteria">{{i.type | criteriaFilter}}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks bro. you save my day. Thanks Larry.